# about datetime.strptime()

Tags: python

I am fairly new with datetime in python, and I am using Python 2.7.3

In the python console:

```
>>>import datetime
>>>datetime.datetime.strptime("2012-3-12 10:10:10", "%Y-%m-%j %H:%M:%S")
```

why the result is following?

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 12, 10, 10, 10)
```

Rather than

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 12, 10, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use `%j` which is the "day of year" and thus it messes up you datetime. It's kind of like trying to turn your car's steering wheel into both directions at the same time - that can't work...

You want `%d` instead:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2012-03-12 10:10:10", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 12, 10, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have read the documentation of python more carefully

Answer (score 1):

It's the `%j` in your format, from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> Day of the year as a decimal number [001,366].

and the 12th day in the year is the 12th of january.

Use `%d` instead:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2012-03-12 10:10:10", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 12, 10, 10, 10)
```