# Errors running python code, attribute error for datetime and strptime type error

Tags: python

I was given a project to complete:

> Help determine how much time someone has left to meet a deadline
>
> - Ask a user to enter the deadline for their project
> - Tell them how many days they have to complete the project
> - For extra credit, give them the answer as a combination of weeks & days (Hint: you will need some of the math functions from the module
>     on numeric values)

Now here is where I come up against a brick wall:

1. I have on my laptop python 2.7.12 while the tutor is using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and teaching cpython.
2. when I run my code it compiles but as soon as I input userdata it gives me the error displayed below.

MY CODE:

```
import datetime
currentday=datetime.date.today()

#set variable to recieve deadline for project
deadLine = 0
deadLine = raw_input('when is the deadline for your project? (dd/mm/YYYY) ')
deadLine=datetime.dateime.strptime(deadLine, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
daysLeft= deadLine-currentday


print 'Number of days left for your project is : '
print daysLeft
```

ERROR GIVEN:

```
when is the deadline for your project? (dd/mm/YYYY) 21/10/2016
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oluwaseun Okungbowa\Desktop\Video editing and python programming\projectdeadline.py", line 7, in <module>
    deadLine=datetime.dateime.strptime(deadLine, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dateime'
```

3. when I tried to run the tutors code, I came up with another error (again these errors are given after accepting input from user.

TUTORS CODE:

```
#import the datetime class
import datetime

#declare and initialize variables
strDeadline = ""
totalNbrDays = 0
nbrWeeks = 0
nbrDays = 0

#Get Today's date
currentDate = datetime.date.today()

#Ask the user for the date of their deadline
strDeadline = input("Please enter the date of your deadline (mm/dd/yyyy): ")

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDeadline,"%m/%d/%Y").date()

#Calculate number of days between the two dates
totalNbrDays = deadline - currentDate

#For extra credit calculate results in weeks & days

nbrWeeks = totalNbrDays.days / 7

#The modulo will return the remainder of the division
#which will tell us how many days are left 
nbrDays = totalNbrDays.days%7

#display the result to the user

print("You have %d weeks" %nbrWeeks + " and %d days " %nbrDays + "until your   deadline.")
```

ERROR GIVEN:

```
Please enter the date of your deadline (mm/dd/yyyy): 10/21/2016

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oluwaseun Okungbowa\Desktop\Video editing and python programming\projectdeadlineteachers.py", line 16, in <module>
    deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDeadline,"%m/%d/%Y").date()
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not int
```

Please help me understand why I am getting both errors when I run the two programs and what I must do to correct it.

Comment: Do not use ALL CAPS in your title; this is considered shouting and is seen as rude behaviour.

Comment: `datetime.dateime` should be `datetime.datetime` .. .and strptime expects a string but instead you gave it an integer (a timestamp i guess... in which case `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` should work...)

Comment: `strptime()`'s first argument needs to be a string not an int.

Comment: if this is python 2, then entering `10/21/2016` in python2 for `input()`, will result in arithmetic operation, giving you a value of 0, which is an integer. just changing `input()` -> `raw_input` should fix it.

Comment: When running the tutor's code you should convert all instances of `input()` to `raw_input()`.

Comment: Also, this site aims to collect questions that are helpful not just to you but to *other visitors*. As such, we don't care much about timelines or urgency, we care about *question quality*. Your question title is not helpful here, as we can't even begin to determine what you need help *with* beyond the broad 'python' subject. Please read [ask] on how to ask questions effectively, which will actually lead to *faster help* as we can start looking at the actual problem rather than the problems with the question itself.

Comment: if you used an ide it would have helped you avoid mis-spelling things at least ...

Comment: Your tutor is using Python 3 (You are using python 2; CPython is the Python reference implementation, see [Python vs Cpython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17130975)). You probably want to install Python 3 at this point to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Also, if the tutor sample code is anything to go by, I can't say I'm impressed with the course quality. There is no need to 'declare' variables in Python first; the whole *declare and initialize variables* block can be done away with with no ill effects. The comment `#import the datetime class` is, at best, imprecise, at worst, horribly confusing to a new Python programmer. The use of `%` on *separate string objects* rather than use *one* `str.format()` formatting string is... idiosyncratic. Etc. I recommend you find a different tutor.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. First of all apologies for using caps in the header,it wasnt intended to be rude but just to get your attention. Secondly i am new to all this,I downloaded the video from youtube and am using the video to learn.please i would beg for a little tenderness as some of the responses are a bit harsh and i was of the opinion are here to help??all in all,upgrade to python 3.got it..Thank you all.really appreciate it

Comment: thank you everyone,changed dateime to datetime on my code and it ran well,also upgrading to latest python as we speak.much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Install python3 so that you and your tutor are on the same page.
>
> However, if you do decide to stick with python 2.7, this will fix your problem.

Your problem is in this line

```
#Ask the user for the date of their deadline
strDeadline = input("Please enter the date of your deadline (mm/dd/yyyy): ")
```

Here's an example of what I mean

```
>>> input()
5
5
>>> input()
10/2
5
>>> input()
10/2/2016
0
```

python is thinking that your date is arithmetic division of integers. change `input()` to `raw_input()` to accept the string.

i.e.

```
strDeadline = raw_input("Please enter the date of your deadline (mm/dd/yyyy): ")
```

Comment: *Or* (and that's a much better idea), the OP could install Python 3 instead and learn with that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, installing python3 will save OP a lot of confusion in the future !

Answer (score 0):

The first error is spelling mistake( datetime not dateime, check yourself, try not to ask stackoverflow for simple things).
Second Error:

Refer to this:
[about datetime.strptime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021108/about-datetime-strptime)

First argument of strptime should be string ( this is what error is saying, errors help you learn better)
so make the first argument
the input was

```
str(deadLine)#converting deadLine to string
```

Edit:
I had neglected the logical error, because of which strDeadLine was an int. 
The problem arrives because IDLE performs the operation( division in this case before providing it to the code). This will not be the case when using Shell, or cmd. I stand with what I said before, the best way to learn is not stack overflow but to try by yourself.
Thanks martijn-pieters for the comment.

Comment: So how do you suggest the integer returned by `input()` is going to be parsed into a `date` object? There are no separate day, month or year components in an integer.

Comment: Thank you abhishek....a bit harsh in your response but thanks.appreciate your help

Comment: in python 2 use raw_input() and hence the result will be a string, which can then be directly passed,